# Access a class from ASPX Code behind page using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, class, code-behind

Im trying to access a class from code behind in javascript but I am getting the error saying it does'nt exist in this context. This has worked for me before this way.

Here is my code:
Code Behind:

```
public class ReviewData
{
    public int NumberOfReviews { get; set; }
    public double AvgReviewScore { get; set; }
}
```

This variable has been populated further down

Here is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var reviewData = "<%=ReviewData%>"
</script>
```

Comment: There are a few issues here... firstly you appear to be trying to instantiate a C# class (server-side) in Javascript (client-side), which won't work. You could create your JS object and set its properties in a similar manner though. What is it you want to achieve?

Comment: Your script makes no sense. You need to access an instance of the C# class, not use the class name. That's just simple OO principles, nothing to do with injecting it into Javascript. And if you want to inject the whole object (not just a single property from it), you need to serialise it to JSON. C# and JS are not just trivially interchangeable, despite some superficial similarities in the syntax.

Comment: @Diado yes but I am using var at the start instead of ReviewData. That might be the problem. Thanks

Comment: @Smac Sorry, I didn't quite grasp what you were doing when I wrote my original comment - have edited it

Comment: "This variable" - which variable? Do you have a server-side object of type `ReviewData`, that you want to send to the browser?

Comment: @Igor I think OP means the JS variable. They seem to have forgotten they need to declare a C# variable as well in order for this to work.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use JSON.Net to serialize your class into a JSON string. Inside your class, create a method called "Serialize()" that returns a string and serializes itself.

In the Javascript, you could then write something like:
`var reviewData = "@ReviewData.Serialize()"`

From there, you may have to use Javascript to parse it back into an object from a string... But you can't pass an actual C# class to Javascript. The best you can do is JSON.

Also, this won't work unless you have an object reference of ReviewData in your codebehind.

Answer (score 1):

Brandon Millers answer is correct if you need to use a list of objects as an array. But if you want to access a single property of a class, you can do this.
Declare it as a public variable

```
public ReviewData reviewData;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    reviewData = new ReviewData();
    reviewData.NumberOfReviews = 5;
}
```

Now you can access the properties of the variable `reviewData` on the aspx.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var reviewData = '<%=reviewData.NumberOfReviews%>';
</script>
```